# Passing bash argument as string

Tags: bash

i have a little and probably very stupid problem..

I'm trying to make an alias for tar and gzip which uses the file name (given as an argument), but it is not converting as expected to the filename in the output.

My alias is:

```
alias targz='tar -cvzf $1.tar.gz $1'
```

It works, but the argument stored in $1 is not working when setting the filename, it zips it in a file called ".tar.gz".

I tried just echoing '$1.tar.gz' and the output is '.tar.gz', so, i think it should be something very stupid in the format.

Any help is welcome,

Comment: You need functions for this (or scripts). Aliases won't do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases don't have positional parameters. They're basically macros (an alias gets replaced with the text of the alias when executed).

You could use a function:

```
targz() {
  tar -cvzf "$1".tar.gz "$1"
}
```

or a script

```
#!/bin/bash  
tar -cvzf "$1".tar.gz "$1"
```

Personally, I've been using something like the following script to achieve a similar goal (comments added for your convenience):

```
#!/bin/bash
#support multiple args
for arg in "$@" 
do
  #strip ending slash if present (tab-completion adds them)
  arg=${arg%/}
  #compress with pigz (faster on multicore systems)
  tar c "$arg" | pigz - > "$arg".tgz 
done
```

In case you want my complete version, I also remove the argument directory if the tarring and compression succeed (similar to what gzip does for individual files)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o pipefail
for arg in "$@" 
do
  arg=${arg%/}
  tar c "$arg" | pigz - > "$arg".tgz && rm -rf "$arg"
done
```

**Update:**
Credits to @mklement0 for the more succinct and more efficient stripping of ending slashes.

Comment: What do u mean by 'Aliases don't have positional parameters'? I've made aliases using positional parameters and they're working fine.

Comment: @Ghost: From the [bash man page, Aliases section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases): "There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text, as in csh. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used (see Shell Functions)."

Comment: I currently have an alias that takes the first pos. parameter and changes mi ethernet mac address to it and it's working..

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks. I've updated the answer with your improvement.

Comment: Well, followed your advice and made a script last night, thanks!!!. What still makes me curious is why my other aliases with pos. parameters work..

Both you and higuaro put a fast & simple answer; i'll accept yours because is more complete, but thanks to all guys =)!!!

Comment: @Ghost Please give us an example where positional arguments work for an alias. As I wrote, aliases are pretty much nothing more than string expansion. Variables such as $1 or $2 specified in an alias will expand to what they would otherwise expand in the context in which you invoke the alias. There are no alias-local $1, $2, ... . Aliases don't run in their own context.

Comment: This one (i have 4 or 5 more like it) -> alias spon='sudo ifconfig en3 ether $1'
I use it to change en3 interface addr to a specific one, giving a MAC as the only parameter.

Comment: @Ghost when you type `spon something` bash will expand it to `sudo ifconfig en3 ether $1 something`. In your common interactive bash environment, $1 will evaluate to an empty string (""), which doesn't get passed through in bash, so your command (sudo) will end up seeing `['ifconfig', 'en3', 'ether', 'something' ]` in its `argv` array. `something` doesn't get passed via $1, althought it may seem like it does. You can set $1 in bash via `set some_value`. If you do that and run `spon something`, it'll end up running `sudo ifconfig en3 ether some_value something`.

Comment: Omg, you're right.. all my $1 calls are are being ignored and the parameters are passed directly... i'm a real genius, im fixing them.. thanks a lot!! =D

Answer (score 1):

Use an alias to a function for it, something like:

```
 alias targz='function targz_() { tar -cvzf "$1.tar.gz" "$1"; return 0; }; targz_ '
```

Comment: What is the advantage of having an alias?  Why not just have a function called `targz`?

Comment: To show the OP that there is a way to mimic positional parameters inside an `alias`

Comment: Seems like a bit of an academic exercise but, OK,  +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a script to do that, like this.

```
echo """

#!/bin/bash if [ -z $1 ]; then
     echo "Variable is Null" 
else
     tar -cvzf $1.tar.gz $1 
fi

""" > /usr/local/bin/targz

chmod +x /usr/local/bin/targz
```

Comment: `echo """ ... """` is the same as `echo " ... "`, and, as a _double_-quoted string, it is instantly subject to (certain) shell expansions, which you do NOT want here. use `echo '...'`.

Comment: Also, not double-quoting the `$1` instances means that the script will break with arguments with embedded spaces.